# Collection of zero tracking number shipments magento

Tags: php, magento

I need to get a collection of shipments that has no tracking numbers associated with it in magento.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeTofilter('track_number', ''); //not working
```

Please give me a solution for this if you have.

Comment: Try `$collection->addAttributeTofilter('track_number', array('null' => true));`

Comment: Thanks, but I think it's not working. Shall I need to join the track shipment model somehow?

Comment: I though you already had shipment collection.

Comment: I think `Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_shipment_track_collection');` model we need to join with my shipment model. But how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I needed the same and managed to get it with the following code (magento 1.9.3):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->getCollection()
      ->addAttributeTofilter('track_number', array('null' => true));

$trackTableName = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/shipment_track');
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('tracking' => $trackTableName), 'main_table.order_id=tracking.order_id',
        array()
);

foreach ($collection as $shipment) {
   print_r($shipment->getData());
}
```